# Tabulator: How to add new row which merge multiple columns on tabulator

Tags: javascript, typescript, datatable, tabulator

Is there any way to add new row which will merge multiple columns on tabulator?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHdv9.png) Something like this, data needs to be spanned on multiple columns.

Other details are added from the ajax call or some other functions, i need to add new row which have some cell spanning multiple columns. The cell not only contains price or something like that it may contains other things too. so calculation is not required.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Maybe by adding footer or other things to achieve this.

I am using typescript, so it will be very helpful if the solution is provided on the typescript.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One way you would be to use the [rowFormatter](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/format#row) option. Below is an example.

PS. This may have some side effects. Notice that column resizing needs to be disabled for the merged columns otherwise it would not resize properly.

```js
const tableData = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Billy Bob', age: '23', gender: 'male', height: 1, col: 'red', dob: '25/03/2000' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May', age: '41', gender: 'female', height: 2, col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Margret Marmajuke', age: '30', gender: 'female', height: 5, col: 'yellow', dob: '31/01/1993' }
]

const table = new Tabulator('#table', {
  layout: 'fitColumns',
  data: tableData,
  columns: [
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name', width: 175, resizable: false },
    { title: 'Age', field: 'age', width: 100, resizable: false },
    { title: 'Gender', field: 'gender', width: 100, resizable: false },
    { title: 'Favourite Color', field: 'col', width: 150 },
    { title: 'Date Of Birth', field: 'dob' }
  ],
  rowFormatter: function (row) {
    const data = row.getData()

    if (data.col === 'blue') {
      const nodes = row.getElement().childNodes
      const [c1, c2, c3, ...remains] = nodes
      const merged = document.createElement('div')
      const mergedWidth =
        parseInt(c1.style.width, 10) + parseInt(c2.style.width, 10) + parseInt(c3.style.width, 10) + 'px'

      merged.style.width = mergedWidth
      merged.className = 'tabulator-cell'
      merged.innerHTML = 'Merged "' + data.name + ' + ' + data.age + ' + ' + data.gender + '"'

      row.getElement().replaceChildren(merged, ...remains)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="table"></div>
</body>
</html>
```